# How to render an HTML table properly in a perl CGI file

Tags: html, perl, cgi

So i am using perl CGI to create a table from arrays in my perl code. i also have HTML implemented in my perl file. I have the content printing out on the browser, but its printing on top of the HTML part of the web page. I want it to be lower so it will display in the actual HTML part of the .pl file. For a better understanding i will post a screenshot of how it loads on the browser.

[image]

Here is my perl code which prints out this data..

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

    use CGI qw/:standard/;
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use JSON qw( decode_json );
    use LWP::Simple 'get'; 
    use Data::Dumper; 

    print "content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";

    my @sessionArr;
    my @classArr;
    my @timeArr;
    my @adminArr;
    my @profArr;
    my @descArr;

    my $i = 0;

    my $myURL = "leaving URL out";

    my $json = get($myURL);
    die "Could not get $myURL!" unless defined $json;

    my $decoded_json = decode_json ($json);

    my @sessionID = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
    foreach my $d ( @sessionID ) {
     $sessionArr[$i] = $d->{"sessionID"};
     $i = $i + 1;
    }

    $i = 0;

    my @class = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
    foreach my $d ( @class ) {
     $classArr[$i] = $d->{"classField"};
     $i = $i + 1;
    }

    $i = 0;


    my @time = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
    foreach my $d ( @time ) {
      $timeArr[$i] = $d->{"startTimeField"};
      $i = $i + 1;
    }

    $i = 0;

    my @usrcreater = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
    foreach my $d ( @usrcreater ) {
      $adminArr[$i] = $d->{"leader"};
      $i = $i + 1;
    }

    $i = 0;

    my @professor = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
    foreach my $d ( @professor ) {
      $profArr[$i] = $d->{"professorField"};
      $i = $i + 1;
    }

    $i = 0;




    my @description = @{ $decoded_json->{'items'} };
    foreach my $d ( @description ) {
      $descArr[$i] = $d->{"descriptionField"};
      $i = $i + 1;
    }

    $i = 0;

    foreach my $p ( @description ) {
       $i = $i +1;
    }

    foreach my $i (0..$#sessionArr) {
        print "<tr>\n";
        print " ";
        foreach my $ra (\@sessionArr, \@classArr, \@timeArr, \@adminArr, \@profArr, \@descArr) {
            print "<td>$ra->[$i]</td>\n"
        }
        print "<h2></tr></h2>\n";
    }


    print qq(<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>


    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <title>AU Study Sessions</title>

        <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.png">
        <script src="../js/pace.js"></script>

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="preloader"></div>

        <! -- ******************** MASTHEAD SECTION ******************** -->    
        <main id="top" class="masthead" role="main">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo"> <a href="http://a3jjddh.com/"><img src="../images/aulogo2.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>

                <h1>View Study Sessions</h1>

    <table> 
<-- *****This is where i want my table to be displayed -->


    </table> 


    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="http://website.com"> Add a Study Session</a>

                    <!--<a href="index.html#explore" class="scrollto">
                    <p>SCROLL DOWN TO EXPLORE</p>
                    <p class="scrollto--arrow"><img src="../images/scroll_down.png" alt="scroll down arrow"></p>
                    </a> -->
            </div><! --/container -->
        </main><! --/main -->


        <! -- ******************** FOOTER SECTION ******************** -->  
        <div class="container" id="explore">



            <div class="section-title">
                <h2>With Adelphi Study Sessions Website</h2>
                <h4>You will be able to do the following</h4>
            </div>

            <section class="row features">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail"> 
                        <img src="../images/service_01.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>View Study Groups</h3>
                            <p>See the most up to date study sessions taking place on our garden city campus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div><! --/thumbnail -->
                </div><! --/col-sm-6-->

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail"> 
                        <img src="../images/service_02.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Add and create new study sessions</h3>
                            <p>If you or some classmates want to create a new study session you will be able to add a new group along with course information, sudy topics, and time and location taking place.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div><! --/thumbnail -->
                </div><! --/col-sm-6-->

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail"> 
                        <img src="../images/service_03.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>See description of session</h3>
                            <p>The student who creates the study session will give a short description about what the study session will cover.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div><! --/thumbnail -->
                </div><! --/col-sm-6-->

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail"> 
                        <img src="../images/service_04.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Available on campus</h3>
                            <p>All study sessions will take place on our Garden City campus therefore are available to all students who commute or live on campus.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div><! --/thumbnail -->
                </div><! --/col-sm-6-->
            </section><! --/section -->







    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/easing.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/nicescroll.js"></script> 


    </body>);
```

Comment: You really need to show your HTML

Comment: Html? or my perl code. keep in mind i have a .pl file with Html embedded inside of it

Comment: Yes that is correct! So how shall I move this around to get it to print in the area I want it to?

Comment: Since the code in the question has changed during discussions, the question (and answers) could be very confusing for a user who comes to this page later.  I have rolled it back to the version where the full code was added.  If you don't like that I very much apologize, please change it to the version you want. You would click on "edited ..." link to the left of your user name, and on the page that comes up you will be able to click on "rollback" link under the version you want.

Comment: @BC0148: You may *add to* your original question to clarify the problem, but please don't edit your original code so that the the problem no longer applies. It makes nonsense of any existing comments and solutions, and should probably be the content of a new question altogether. I encouraged ***zdim*** to roll back to edit 4 as edit 5 changes the question completey and everything afterwards is only cosmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rewrite that uses [Template Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/index.html) ("TT") to build the HTML page and include the data from your JSON

There are many problems with your original HTML. Tags are unbalanced, and you have head-only elements within the body. I can't guarantee that this fixes everything but I can't spot any more errors. You should be careful to keep your HTML indented so that you can more easily spot unbalanced tags. It also obviates the need to comment the closing tags

I've included a block of code that shows you how to more easily extract arrays of the same field from each of a list of hashes. The variables aren't used, so please delete that code once you've understood the lesson

The templates for Template Toolkit are normally held in separate `.tt` files. In this case I've used the `DATA` file handle as it's more in keeping with the way you wrote your original code. But bear in mind that a TT template may contain `include` statements that refer to other separate files. For instance you could put your footer section in an external file and then `[% INCLUDE footer.tt %]` in your main template. But that is for the future

Note that Template Toolkit allows you to access Perl data structures directly. Anything that the template needs to use must be passed in the second parameter of the `process` methods call. In this case I have passed `{ json => $decoded_json }` so that TT can now use the `json` identifier to refer to the hash that you have downloaded. Within the template, `json.items` is now the array of data (accessible as `json.items.0`, `json.items.1` etc.) and here I have written `[% FOREACH item IN json.items %]` which declares a new TT variable `item` and assigns it to each element of the `items` array in turn

I hope all of that is clear

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use CGI qw/:standard/;
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use LWP;
use Template;

use Data::Dumper; 

use constant JSON_URL => 'http://example.com/json';

### This code uses a literal JSON data item. The live code should
### fetch the real data from the JSON_URL. The code to do this
### is here but has been commented out

=comment
my $json = do {
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $resp = $ua->get(JSON_URL);
    unless ( $resp->is_success ) {
        die sprintf "Could not retrieve JSON data: %s", $resp->status_line;
    }
    $resp->decoded_content;
};
=cut

my $json = <<END;
{
    "items": [
        {
            "sessionID":        "session1",
            "classField":       "class1",
            "startTimeField":   "start1",
            "leader":           "leader1",
            "professorField":   "prof1",
            "descriptionField": "desc1"
        },
        {
            "sessionID":        "session2",
            "classField":       "class2",
            "startTimeField":   "start2",
            "leader":           "leader2",
            "professorField":   "prof2",
            "descriptionField": "desc2"
        }
    ]
}
END

my $decoded_json = decode_json($json);


### Note that these variables are unused. This is just an example
### of a better way to extract a list of values from an array of hashes
### Please remove this code before deploying

my $items = $decoded_json->{items};

my @sessionArr = map { $_->{sessionID} } @$items;
my @classArr   = map { $_->{classField} } @$items;
my @timeArr    = map { $_->{startTimeField} } @$items;
my @adminArr   = map { $_->{leader} } @$items;
my @profArr    = map { $_->{professorField} } @$items;
my @descArr    = map { $_->{descriptionField} } @$items;

### All that needs to be done its to use CGI to print the HTTP
### header and invoke Template Toolkit to build an HTML page that
### includes the data from the JSON hash

print CGI->header(
    -type    => 'text/html',
    -charset => 'utf-8',
);

my $tt = Template->new;

$tt->process(\*DATA, { json => $decoded_json } );

__DATA__
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>AU Study Sessions</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.png">
    <script src="../js/pace.js"></script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="preloader"></div>

    <!-- ******************** MASTHEAD SECTION ******************* -->

    <main id="top" class="masthead" role="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href=""><img src="../images/aulogo2.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>

            <h1>View Study Sessions</h1>);

            <table>

            [% FOREACH item IN json.items %]
            <tr>
                <td>[% item.sessionID %]</td>
                <td>[% item.classField %]</td>
                <td>[% item.startTimeField %]</td>
                <td>[% item.leader %]</td>
                <td>[% item.professorField %]</td>
                <td>[% item.descriptionField %]</td>
            </tr>
            [% END %]

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <a href=""> Add a Study Session</a>

            <!--
            <a href="index.html#explore" class="scrollto">
                <p>SCROLL DOWN TO EXPLORE</p>
                <p class="scrollto--arrow"><img src="../images/scroll_down.png" alt="scroll down arrow"></p>
            </a>
            -->

        </div> <!-- class="container" -->
    </main>

    <!-- ******************** FOOTER SECTION ******************** -->  

    <div class="container" id="explore">

        <div class="section-title">
            <h2>With Adelphi Study Sessions Website</h2>
            <h4>You will be able to do the following</h4>
        </div>

        <section class="row features">

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_01.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>View Study Groups</h3>
                        <p>See the most up to date study sessions taking place on our garden city campus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_02.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Add and create new study sessions</h3>
                        <p>If you or some classmates want to create a new study session you will be able to add a new group along with course information, sudy topics, and time and location taking place.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_03.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>See description of session</h3>
                        <p>The student who creates the study session will give a short description about what the study session will cover.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_04.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Available on campus</h3>
                        <p>All study sessions will take place on our Garden City campus therefore are available to all students who commute or live on campus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>

        <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/easing.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/nicescroll.js"></script>

    </div> <!-- class="container" id="explore" -->

</body>

</html>
```

#### output

```html
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>AU Study Sessions</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../images/favicon.png">
    <script src="../js/pace.js"></script>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="preloader"></div>

    <!-- ******************** MASTHEAD SECTION ******************* -->

    <main id="top" class="masthead" role="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href=""><img src="../images/aulogo2.png" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>

            <h1>View Study Sessions</h1>);

            <table>


            <tr>
                <td>session1</td>
                <td>class1</td>
                <td>start1</td>
                <td>leader1</td>
                <td>prof1</td>
                <td>desc1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>session2</td>
                <td>class2</td>
                <td>start2</td>
                <td>leader2</td>
                <td>prof2</td>
                <td>desc2</td>
            </tr>


            <br/>
            <br/>

            <a href=""> Add a Study Session</a>

            <!--<a href="index.html#explore" class="scrollto">
            <p>SCROLL DOWN TO EXPLORE</p>
            <p class="scrollto--arrow"><img src="../images/scroll_down.png" alt="scroll down arrow"></p>
            </a> -->

        </div>
    </main>


    <!-- ******************** FOOTER SECTION ******************** -->  
    <div class="container" id="explore">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h2>With Adelphi Study Sessions Website</h2>
            <h4>You will be able to do the following</h4>
        </div>

        <section class="row features">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_01.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>View Study Groups</h3>
                        <p>See the most up to date study sessions taking place on our garden city campus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div><! --/thumbnail -->
            </div><! --/col-sm-6-->

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_02.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Add and create new study sessions</h3>
                        <p>If you or some classmates want to create a new study session you will be able to add a new group along with course information, sudy topics, and time and location taking place.</p>
                    </div>
                </div><! --/thumbnail -->
            </div><! --/col-sm-6-->

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_03.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>See description of session</h3>
                        <p>The student who creates the study session will give a short description about what the study session will cover.</p>
                    </div>
                </div><! --/thumbnail -->
            </div><! --/col-sm-6-->

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail"> 
                    <img src="../images/service_04.png" alt="analytics-icon">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3>Available on campus</h3>
                        <p>All study sessions will take place on our Garden City campus therefore are available to all students who commute or live on campus.</p>
                    </div>
                </div><! --/thumbnail -->
            </div><! --/col-sm-6-->
        </section><! --/section -->

        <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/easing.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/nicescroll.js"></script> 

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your code first generates the markup for the table (`print`s it) and then the rest of the web page's HTML. If this is the case, the following may be useful.

Here is HTML for a "web page", with a table. When displayed in a browser this will show the table, along with other contents, formatted and styled in whatever way it is set up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- metadata: links, styling, etc -->
<body>
<!-- ... some HTML ... -->
<table>
<tr>  <td>a</td> <td>A</td> </tr>
<tr>  <td>b</td> <td>B</td> </tr>
</table>
<!-- ... more HTML ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

You can generate this text from Perl by doing `print "<!DOCTYPE html>\n"` etc, line by line.

However, this is something else

```
<table>
<tr>  <td>a</td> <td>A</td> </tr>
<tr>  <td>b</td> <td>B</td> </tr>
</table>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- metadata: head, links, styling, etc -->
<body>    
<!-- ... some HTML ... -->
<!-- ... more HTML ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

When this is thrown at the browser none of the web page styling and other elements will be applied to the table. The browser will merely show the data, `a A` and `b B`, in a puritan tabular layout -- and then the (rest of the intended) web page. (Further, in your code I don't see the `<table>` tags printed so I would expect a browser to show one line with `a A b B`.)

It seems that this is happening in your code. It first prints the table, then the actual page. So it is generating the above markup, from the second example. Change your program so that the HTML markup for the table (that the `print`s generate) lands among the rest of HTML, where you need to place the table.

I hope this helps.  For more detail, or if this is off the mark, please show your HTML and how it's made.

---

Given that the question was updated with full code here is a simple fix, needing only a very small change. PLease note that this is not a comment on how to generate HTML, nor a recommendation for writing it in this way.

After the table's data is printed, the HTML for the page is generated using

```
print qq(<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>
    ... HTML markup goes for screenfuls ...
 </body>);
```

You are using the `qq` operator, which is a generic way to form double quoted strings. It can also use delimiters other than `()`, so you can say `qq{...}` etc. Part of the table at [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

> ```
> Customary Generic   Meaning       Interpolates
>     ''      q{}     Literal         no
>     ""     qq{}     Literal         yes
>     ``     qx{}     Command         yes*
>            qw{}     Word list       no
> ...
>     <<EOF           here-doc        yes*
>     * unless the delimiter is ''.
> ```

Please see the link for the full table and the rest.

So your code is practically the same as

```
print "<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>

<head>
  ...
</body>";
```

except that in this version you'd have to escape double quotes anywhere in the text. Yet another way of doing this is by using *here-doc*.

The `qq` operator interpolates variables, *and includes newlines*.  This means that the above is really

```
print "<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>\n";
print "\n";
print "<head>\n";
# ...
print "</body>\n";
```

I hope that now things are clear. Your `qq(...)` merely sends a very long string (with newlines), your HTML text -- which is equivalent to `print`ing each line separately. You need to insert the table generation code into this.

Here is a simple way to change your code to do that. It is not good code but it should work with least changes to what you have. Break up your `qq` into two.  The first `qq(...);` prints HTML up to the table. Then print the table (move the code that prints it). Then have another `qq(...);` print the rest.

```
# Print HTML up to where the table needs to be
print qq(<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body>
         ... 
            <h1>View Study Sessions</h1>
);

# Now generate markup for the table
print "<table>\n";
foreach my $i (0..$#sessionArr) {
    # rest of table-data printing code
}
print "</table>\n";

# Now resume generating the rest of your HTML
print qq(
<br>
<br>
<a href="http://website.com"> Add a Study Session</a>
... rest of your HTML
</body>
);
```

Please note: *this is not good code*. It is hard to review, modify, extend, and maintain. I'd still suggest that you do this first, to promptly see how a page is generated.  Then reach out and find a better way to produce HTML out of Perl code. I don't use modules for that so cannot recommend any, but there is quite a bit out there.

Comment: @BC0148  You have a space where you can't, in `= for`.  It must be `=for`.

Comment: @BC0148  Final comment on code.  These kinds of problems, little errors with getting the code to run etc, is a reflection of the fact that the code isn't organized well and that printing HTML is messy, etc.  (That's a kind of a thing I meant by saying "_not good code_" in my answer.)  It's just hard to work with a lot of code and text just running down the page. If you are going to be doing web stuff with Perl do investigate modules.  There are many great ones, for generating HTML as well.

Comment: Ok sounds good. i went ahead and deleted the rest of my uncessary comments. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There's a big problem with your sequencing of the HTML output that I'm sure you could see if you ran your program from the command line

The first thing your code does is send the HTTP header with

```
print "content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
```

That should be okay

Then you fetch some JSON data from the internet and decode it. That data must be an array of hashes, which you unpack into six separate arrays. That's unnecessary but it does no harm, and I can understand you choosing to do it that way if you're unfamiliar with Perl references

Right after that your loop starting with this line

```
 foreach my $i (0..$#sessionArr) {
```

prints a number of `<tr>` elements, each with six `<td>` items whose contents come from your six arrays

That's the *first thing* your CGI code is sending back to the client after the `Content-Type` HTTP header. No `<html>` or `<body>` or even `<table>`. That's a bit wrong, but even so your browser does its best and displays the information with the missing elements defaulted

*Then* you send the document type declaration and the rest of the page, where you have put

```
and below here is just html 
---this section is where im trying to get the data to display
```

which is really as important as the rest of the Perl code, and what I asked to see

Your Perl program will send the text in the order you print it. It won't know to insert your `<tr>` elements inside the appropriate `<table>`. As I said, you should be able to see what your code produces by running it from the command line

The usual solution to this is to use a *template* module. [`Template`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template) is the big one but there are many others

Of course you may just scatter `print` statements through your program in the correct order, but that will make your code much less intelligible

I hope that helps

Comment: Ok i see many things are wrong with my file from what you stated. I have now posted my entire file so you can get a better idea of whats going on here. Hope to hear back soon. thanks